# MySQL Data Type

Tags: mysql, store, sqldatatypes

I am uncertain how to store a certain type of data in a MySQL table that contains both numeric and characters. For example, in a tournament, Round contains integers `1,2,3,...30` as well as `QF, SF, GF` for Quarter-Finals, Semi-Finals, and Grand-Finals respectively.

Have tried `VARCHAR(2)`, `CHAR(2)`, `ENUM('1', '2', ... , 'GF')`, `TEXT`

None of which seems to have accepted the data properly. What would be the best or data type way to store the Round data?

Comment: how about 2 data types

Comment: What do you mean by "None of which seems to have accepted the data properly" ? In which sense? Do you have any code to show us the actual issue?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would go with just `INT` type, assigning Quarter-Finals, Semi-Finals, and Grand-Finals to some specific values that are out of range in your domain (e.g. -1, -2, -3 or 31, 32, 33 respectively).

This way you can easily do searches, use indexes, order your resultsets.

Do your translation to human readable values in you presentation layer, or you can do that on MySql side like this

```
SELECT id,
       CASE `round` 
           WHEN -1 THEN 'QF'
           WHEN -2 THEN 'SF'
           WHEN -3 THEN 'GF'
           ELSE `round`
       END round
  FROM tournament
```

Sample output

```
| ID | ROUND |
--------------
|  1 |     1 |
|  1 |     2 |
|  1 |     3 |
|  1 |    QF |
|  1 |    SF |
|  1 |    GF |
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/45194/1)**

Comment: @I_do_LaTeX Do you need more help with your question?